# Two Bernoullian sums being equal

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
& X=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n \\
& Y=b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n \\
& W=b_1+b_2+\cdots+b_n+b_{n+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $a_i$ 's and $b_i$ 's he iid distributed Bernoullian variates with $P\left(a_i=1\right)=P\left(b_i=1\right)=1 / 2$ and
$$
P\left(a_i=-1\right)=P\left(b_i=-1\right)=\frac{1}{2} \text { for all } i=1,2, \ldots
$$
I  want to compute **(a)** $P(|X|=|Y|)$ 
 and
**(b)** $P(|X|=|W|)$.Here is my attempt 
**Solution:** **Part (a)** Let $n$ be even.
In  this case both $X$ and $Y$ Can take only even values from the set $\{0, \pm 2, \ldots, \pm n\}$ Now if $,|X|=|Y|=i, i>0$, we have $(X, Y)=(i, i),(i,-i),(-i, i)$ or $(-i,-i)$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
& P(|X|=|Y|)=4 \sum_{i=2}^n \mathbb{P}(X=i) \cdot P(Y=i) \\
& +\mathbb{P}(X=0)^2 \\
& =4 \sum_{i=2}^n \mathbb{P}(X=i)^2+\mathbb{P}(X=0)^2 \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, $P(X=i)=\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{\frac{n+i}{2} } i,$  even
Hence
$$
P(|X|=|Y|)=2^{2-2 n} \sum_{\substack{i=2 \\
\text { i \text{even} }}}^n \binom{n}{\frac{n+i}{2}}+\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}^2 \frac{1}{2^n} 
$$

As for **Part(b)**, in this case, $W \neq 0$, and $X \neq \pm(n+1)$.
$P(|X|=|W|)=0$, as $X$ and $W$ take vales different in parity. Therefore,when $n$ is odd:
Hence :
$$
P(|X|=|Y|)=2^{2-2 n} \sum_{\substack{i=1 \\
\text { i \text{odd} }}}^n \binom{n}{\frac{n+i}{2}} \frac{1}{2^{2 n}}
.$$ Kindly let me  know if there is any mistake in the solution.I would be highly obliged

Answer (score -1):

Your work appears correct, but you can get a simpler answer.

There are two ways the event $\{|X|=|Y|\}$ can occur. We either have $X=Y$, in which case $X-Y=0$, or we have $X=-Y$, in which case $X+Y=0$. Therefore, letting $E_+$ be the event that $X+Y=0$, and $E_-$ be the event that $X-Y=0$,
$$
P(|X|=|Y|)=P(E_+\cup E_-)=P(E_+)+P(E_-)-P(E_+\cap E_-)
$$
To compute $P(E_+)$, note that $X+Y$ is a sum of $2n$ independent $\text{Unif}\{\pm1\}$ random variables. This means $X+Y=0$ if and only if exactly $n$ of out $2n$ of these variables are positive, so $P(E_+)=\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}$.

To compute $P(E_-)$, note that $X-Y$ has the exact same distribution of $X+Y$; this is because $Y$ is equal in distribution to $-Y$. Therefore, $P(E_-)=P(E_+)$.

Finally, if $n$ is even, we have $$P(E_+\cap E_-)=P(X+Y=0\cap X-Y=0)=P(X=0\cap Y=0)=\left[\binom{n}{n/2}2^{-n}\right]^2.$$ If $n$ is odd, the probability of the intersection is zero.

This same method applies to part (b); I would leave filling in the details as an exercise to you.

Comment: This answer is numerically correct, which I [confirmed with Python simulation.](https://tio.run/##fVLJboMwED3HXzGXSnYaRKDppRL/kaiqIkNMYxGPkW2k5uvpmK1pupyG4XneMnZ7DWeLT31fO2vASTxR0aa1LkB1trpSng2QkeEMMEO1rIJ1Wl4YO6maQI1cvLAVQgHZlq1apzFwr013kUGdjq2zpSz1RYcrRyHmA@qDeH6AA2WI7NQS6Z5IJy/8Nck22dsGGvqHxHP4B3MqdA5Blp77zvC9EFAUS3uYlf5wuQHszHGw4YdUsF7DM/mhlAT4riJNryJGgWvr4Aga4wrfFf8ajQHuBh6LJd1i8vuJ9EZ7NFlZU0ZPTeSbZpZLICJI05u@uesxaaawv208RtI1IDxAHjeURcuTxnZRy2E9uogfcTuC6i4uJUFIgM8OMU3zCOUjJGLJGRufSN9/Ag)